# Very slow compilation in VS after changing the "regional and language" settings

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, build, regional-settings

My VS C++ project had manye C4819 warnings ": The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss"

Following https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9fd910a5-08dc-4202-b1e0-15aeaf3fba4e/action?threadDisplayName=vstudio&forum=vclanguage, I changed the regional and language option of the OS. Now there is no more C4819 warnings, but the compilation (and overall performance) is very slow. It can be up to 5 times slower...

How is it possible and how to get the original performance back?

Comment: Write all your comments in English (or at least with a character set that is "ok" for English/Latin alphabet), and don't use Unicode? I'm assuming you have compared  "with" and "without" this setting to ensure that is exactly what the problem is...

Comment: It is excessively unlikely that this change could cause such a drastic slowdown, you'll have to look in another corner.  Not otherwise the real fix, save your file in utf-8 with a BOM.  Use File > Advanced Save Options, you like Encoding = "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".  Now you don't have to mess with the OS default code page, the compiler is never confused about the source file encoding and can tackle any character in the source code.

Comment: @HansPassant Why is it unlikely ? And this raises the question: what could be the cause(s) of my slow build?